# vue-slick sliding arrows are not visible in vuejs component

Tags: vue.js

I am working with vue-slick(v-1.1.15) in vuejs to show some sliding images. Although the images are auto-slidable but I also need arrows to make them slide manually.
The problem is instead of those arrows, two buttons "Next" and "Previous" are being shown.

I have also imported the .css file for vue-slick to get it work, but useful results were found.

Below is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="idb-full-block">
        <slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions" v-if="someVar !== null">
            <div class="content-wrap" v-for="var in someVar" :key="var.img">
                <div class="idb-block-content p-20">
                    <div class="pp-image mb-20 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <img :src="var.img" class="img-fluid" alt="pp" width="" height="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-10">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">{{var.title}}</h5>
                        <h5 class="text-danger mb-0 fw-bold">{{var.price}}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pp-ratings">
                        <i v-for="(stars, index) in 5" :key="index" class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="pp-stats footer-border">
                    <li class="w-33">
                        <h4 class="fw-bold">{{var.sales}}</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li class="w-33">
                        <h4 class="fw-bold">{{var.rating}}</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li class="w-33">
                        <h4 class="fw-bold">{{var.comments}}</h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </slick>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import Slick from "vue-slick";
import { someVar } from "./someVar.js";
import `node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css`;

export default {
components: {
    Slick
},
data() {
    return {
        someVar,
        slickOptions: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            arrows: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
        },          
    }
},
};
</script>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is webpack compiling the code? The class for the arrows should have "slick-next slick-arrow" on a button element. It is possible your font-awesome class declarations are overriding this causing the webpack to not compile the slick component properly.

Comment: also, possibly copy the slick.css file to your project and reference it directly like your own css files. Webpack might not be picking up the node_modules folder making your buttons not render the slick css arrows that your expecting.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer in other Question

**You need to**

- Making sure you passing arrows props as true
- the default color and background is white so you need to change
  it first if your website is white.
- Using slot {nextArrow, prevArrow }

```css
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
        <template #prevArrow="arrowOption">
          <div class="custom-arrow">
            {{ arrowOption.currentSlide }}/{{ arrowOption.slideCount }}
          </div>
        </template>
        <template #nextArrow="arrowOption">
          <div class="custom-arrow">
            {{ arrowOption.currentSlide }}/{{ arrowOption.slideCount }}
          </div>
        </template>
```